# Ensure no LocalDateTime.now() with no arguments with Archunit, but accept LocalDateTime.now(clock)

Tags: java, junit5, archunit

I am pretty new to Archunit and I am struggling to find in the docs how to make a rule that allow usage of `LocalDateTime.now(clock)` but forbids usage of `LocalDateTime.now()` (no argument)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IDE with code completion, you can browse the fluent API by starting with `noClasses().should().`… and looking at the suggestions. (Instead of `classes`/`noClasses`, you may also find other [`ArchRuleDefinition`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/ArchRuleDefinition.html)s like `fields`/`noFields` or `codeUnits`/`noCodeUnits` useful).

In your case, you might discover [`callMethod`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#callMethod(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)), where the provided method parameter types allow you to distinguish `LocalDateTime.now()` from `LocalDateTime.now(clock)`:

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule no_LocalDateTime_now_without_clock = com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition
     .noClasses()
     .should().callMethod(LocalDateTime.class, "now" /* without parameters */)
     .because("we want to use `LocalDateTime.now(clock)` instead");
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help! How would it look like in the hypothetical case where I would wish to allow `now()` and forbid `now(clock)`?

Comment: nvm, I just understood, you would have `.callMethod(LocalDateTime.class, "now" , Clock.class)`

Comment: Right: `callMethod(LocalDateTime.class, "now", Clock.class)` selects calls to `LocalDateTime.now` with exactly one `Clock` parameter.